# MS Access Database Connection with C# under ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, asp.net-core, appsettings

I am trying to connect my new Project (ASP.Net Core Framework) with `Access Database`.

What do I need to enter into: `appsettings.json ->  "ConnectionStrings"?`

And do I have to install something for it?

This framework is new and unfortunately I found no much on the Internet.

I need to connect exactly "Access database".

I would be very happy for detailed information.

Comment: Does this help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hktw939c(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Migration to SQL Server is not applicable ??

Answer (score 4):

Use the "[Access Database Engine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)", which provides an ODBC interface to your application.  Be sure to use the 64-bit version (since dotnet core is 64 bit only).    Note that it is safe for single-threaded access only. Use the passive parameter at install since the additional Access components are not needed.

`AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe /passive`

Comment: Notice that the connection string format is @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=<pathtofile>";

Comment: Why is it only safe for single-threaded access? That's not a limitation on the OleDB drivers for Access.

Comment: From the link "The Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable is not intended:
...
where the code will run under a system account, or will deal with multiple users identities concurrently, or is highly reentrant and expects stateless behavior."

Answer (score 2):

From this link :
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/09/net-core-data-access/

> What about OLE DB?
>
> OLE DB has been a great way to access various data sources in a
>   uniform manner, but it was based on COM, which is a Windows-only
>   technology, and as such was not the best fit for a cross-platform
>   technology such as .NET Core. It is also unsupported in SQL Server
>   versions 2014 and later. For those reasons, OLE DB won’t be supported
>   by .NET Core.

Comment: It is wrong that OLD DB was dropped. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2011/08/29/microsoft-is-aligning-with-odbc-for-native-relational-data-access/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Entity Framework Core` which is highly recommended for `ASP.net Core` applications. Also there are a lot of tutorials out there for using it.

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/) lists a suitable Provider for EF Core:

> [EntityFrameworkCore.Jet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.Jet/)  -> Microsoft Access files

Please make sure [reading the limitations](https://github.com/bubibubi/EntityFrameworkCore.Jet/wiki/Limitations) first from the GitHub Page and check if it's still passes your requirements.

*Personally i haven't used it yet, but i'm pretty sure that the whole thing can't be too complicated.*

Comment: This should be the answer. Alas, 4.6.1 dependency.

Comment: So that means that this will not work in an asp.net core 2.2 web application right?

Answer (score -4):

Looks here:  https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Specifically, here:  https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Also, try this.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Odbc; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            OdbcConnection cnn ;
            connetionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=yourdatabasename.mdb;";
            cnn = new OdbcConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                MessageBox.Show ("Connection Open ! ");
                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try this as well...

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            OleDbConnection cnn ;
            connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=yourdatabasename.mdb;";
            cnn = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                MessageBox.Show ("Connection Open ! ");
                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question is about ASP.Net core specifically, not a "standard" .Net application. Windows forms, and the `System.Data.OleDb`/`System.Data.Odbc` namespaces are not available.