# How to Connect .NET Core ASP Application to MS Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create an **.net core asp mvc** app which will read/write to an **MS Access** database.

I can't seem to find any information on how this can be achieved, or whether it is in fact possible, apart from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320008/ms-access-database-connection-with-c-sharp-under-asp-net-core), but none of the answeres there actually give any useful informtion.

For instance the top answer suggests using **Access Database Engine**, but there is no mention on how to actually connect to it.

The next answer talks about using **Jet**, but I got stuck with [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837467/could-not-load-type-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-internal-ientitymate), and it seems that its not actually supported in dotnet core..

Is it actually the case that I can't access a `.mdb` file using dotnet core?

If it is possible, could anyone point me towards some sample code or give any guidance as to how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom *Connection String* that will allow you to access the `.mdb` file.
Use [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/) as your connection string building reference.

You could then instantiate a connection towards the database like this:

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)){

     connection.Open();

}
```

Comment: I can't seem to call `OleDbConnection` (no such class or type)

Comment: have you tried adding `using System.Data.OleDb;` to the beginning of the file? Also you might need to import that reference manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of OLE DB is deprecated in `.net core` as per [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/09/net-core-data-access/) article.

> **What about OLE DB?** 
>   OLE DB has been a great way to access various data sources in a uniform manner, but it was based on COM, which is a
>   Windows-only technology, and as such was not the best fit for a
>   cross-platform technology such as .NET Core. It is also unsupported in
>   SQL Server versions 2014 and later. For those reasons, OLE DB won’t be
>   supported by .NET Core.